# Installing Nifi outside of Hadoop Cluster

Tags: apache-nifi

Usually I have seen Apache Nifi is installed  on Edge node , so that all hadoop related processor can easily talk to hadoop cluster.

Is that a recommended approach ? How much difference it will create having Nifi installed outside of hadoop cluster?

Answer (score 0):

NiFi can run anywhere you want, but in order to communicate with Hadoop you will need to make sure there is appropriate network connectivity from the server running NiFi to all of the Hadoop components (name node, data nodes, etc).

Comment: Do you suggest this approach for production environment where Nifi data pipeline processors continuously interacting with Hadoop cluster ? Reason for hiving this because HDP and HDF can  be placed on single cluster, so I was looking for alternative for this.